# Ajax Cascading DropDownLists with web service don't work on server, the lists are empty

Tags: asp.net, ajax, drop-down-menu, web, cascading

I need help with ajax cascading dropdownlists which work perfectly on my local computer but when i deployed it on server all dropdownlists are empty, without any error message! 
Can anyone please help me? 
My Code is:`

```
                            <ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="code_CascadingDropDown" 
                                runat="server" TargetControlID="code" LoadingText="Loding ..."
                                PromptText="Select Code" ServiceMethod="GetCodes" ServicePath="~/WebService.asmx"
                                Category="Code" UseContextKey="True" Enabled="true">
                            </ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown>

                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="type" runat="server" BackColor="White" Height="22px" 
                            TabIndex="5" Width="170px" >
                                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="type_CascadingDropDown" 
                                runat="server" TargetControlID="type" Enabled="True"
                                ParentControlID="code" LoadingText="Loding ..." PromptText="Select Type" 
                                ServiceMethod="GetType" ServicePath="~/WebService.asmx"
                                Category="type" UseContextKey="True">
                            </ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="dem" runat="server" BackColor="White" Height="22px"
                                TabIndex="6" Width="170px">
                                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="dem_CascadingDropDown" 
                                runat="server" TargetControlID="dem" Enabled="True"
                                ParentControlID="type" LoadingText="Loding ..." PromptText="Select Dimension" 
                                ServiceMethod="GetDimension" ServicePath="~/WebService.asmx"
                                Category="dimension" UseContextKey="True">
                            </ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="p" runat="server" BackColor="White" Height="22px" 
                            TabIndex="7" Width="130px" style="margin-top: 0px">
                                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="p_CascadingDropDown" 
                                runat="server" TargetControlID="p" Enabled="True"
                                ParentControlID="dem" LoadingText="Loding ..." PromptText="Select P" 
                                ServiceMethod="GetP" ServicePath="~/WebService.asmx"
                                Category="p" UseContextKey="True">
                            </ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="minquant" runat="server" BackColor="White" Height="22px" 
                            TabIndex="7" Width="100px" style="margin-top: 0px"><asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;<ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="minquant_CascadingDropDown" runat="server" 
                                TargetControlID="minquant"  Enabled="True"
                                ParentControlID="p" LoadingText="Loding ..." PromptText="Pcs/Carton" 
                                ServiceMethod="GetQuantity" ServicePath="~/WebService.asmx"
                                Category="quantity" UseContextKey="True">
                            </ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown>`

 [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    public WebService()
    {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components
        //InitializeComponent();
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public CascadingDropDownNameValue[] GetCodes(string knownCategoryValues, string category)
    {
        OrdersDataContext db = new OrdersDataContext();
        IEnumerable<CascadingDropDownNameValue> vals = null;
        short targetID = 0;
        vals = (from c in db.codeTs
               select new CascadingDropDownNameValue
               {
                   name = c.code,
                   value = c.id.ToString(),
               }).OrderBy(t => t.name);
        return vals.ToArray<CascadingDropDownNameValue>();
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public CascadingDropDownNameValue[] GetType(string knownCategoryValues, string category)
    {
        OrdersDataContext db = new OrdersDataContext();
        IEnumerable<CascadingDropDownNameValue> vals = null;
        StringDictionary kv = CascadingDropDown.ParseKnownCategoryValuesString(knownCategoryValues);
        short code_Id;
        if (!kv.ContainsKey("code") || !short.TryParse(kv["code"], out code_Id))
        {
            return null;
        }
        vals = (from tp in db.typeTs
               where tp.codeId == code_Id
               select new CascadingDropDownNameValue
               {
                   name = tp.type,
                   value = tp.id.ToString(),
               }).OrderBy(t => t.name);
        return vals.ToArray<CascadingDropDownNameValue>();
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public CascadingDropDownNameValue[] GetDimension(string knownCategoryValues, string category)
    {
        OrdersDataContext db = new OrdersDataContext();
        IEnumerable<CascadingDropDownNameValue> vals = null;
        StringDictionary kv = CascadingDropDown.ParseKnownCategoryValuesString(knownCategoryValues);
        short type_Id;
        if (!kv.ContainsKey("type") || !short.TryParse(kv["type"], out type_Id))
        {
            return null;
        }
        vals = (from tp in db.dimTs
               where tp.typeId == type_Id
               select new CascadingDropDownNameValue
               {
                   name = tp.dimension,
                   value = tp.id.ToString(),
               }).OrderBy(t => t.name); 
        return vals.ToArray<CascadingDropDownNameValue>();
    }`
```

Comment: if anyone want to check it may visit this page http://smirdex.gr/OrderForm2.2/LogIn.aspx and use for username abins_Aimilios and pass: 5a>=nBiQR?MDe+ Thank you in advance!!!!

Comment: I logged in.Which page on your site do you have these?

Comment: in the Order Form, sorry i forget to write about...

Comment: I would suggest  making your order button much more conspicuous on your site.I want to help ,browsed your  products but still cant navigate to the order form to replicate your problem..How do I do that.

Comment: Thank you!!! you need to login and after, on the right site there is a menu, click on Order Form, you will see 5 dropdownlists wich are empty...Thank you again for your time!

Comment: Thanks.I got hold of the order form now.

Comment: Did you register ScriptResourceHandler in system.webServer section?

Answer (score 0):

The Web service.asmx  methods are  not being fired at all when I inspect the  network request through firebug .The url is not being resolved correctly.Try putting the full path to your website Service path Like this

```
ServicePath="http://smirdex.gr/OrderForm2.2/WebService.asmx"
```

**Or resolve the url**

```
ServicePath="<%# ResolveUrl('~/OrderForm2.2/WebServices.asmx') %>"
```

Let me know how it goes

Update.This [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkWxN.jpg) shows on your site
Make sure the Ajax Control Toolkit dll was copied in the bin folder when you published your site.

And try a solution on this [link](http://forums.asp.net/p/1209962/2132128.aspx#2132128)

Comment: i try both ways and there is no result...:( right now i have the first"ServicePath="http://smirdex.gr/OrderForm2.2/WebService.asmx""

Comment: You have an error on your site.  

Sys.Application.add_init(function() { failed to load).Check your javascript on top of your page

Comment: Send me a zipped copy of your project and database. abidmix@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. Tt worked then stopped after I install additional role services.  Then after scatched my head for several hours, I found out that in the site's Handler Mappings, one script method for *.asmx has wrong version number! look for public token: B03F5F7F11D50A3A, if you see version 2.0.0.0, then delete it. That's it.